# Finding Eigenvalues of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

I don't understand why there are no eigenvalues for the operator $A_f (t) = \cos(t)f(t)$ in $L^2(S^1;C)$

Comment: Using the definition : we have $cos(t)f(t) = \lambda f(t)$

Comment: No eigenvalues whatsoever or no _real_ eigenvalues?

Comment: No eigenvectors whatsoever. But you can define eigenvalues so that every point in $[0,1]$ is one. If you want a spectral theory for non-compact operators you need to use direct integral theory and spectral measures (ie: "infinitesimal eigenfunctions")